# Flutter unable to debug macos app with debugger (Flutter Attach)

Tags: flutter, intellij-idea, flutter-desktop

I am trying to debug macos app in IntelliJ IDEA IDE and after i click "Flutter Attach" option I see only:

```
Waiting for a connection from Flutter on macOS...
```

which never changes.
Is it possible to debug macos application in IntelliJ?

Answer (score 1):

Attaching to a desktop Flutter application requires attaching via observatory URL, which [IntelliJ doesn't currently support](https://github.com/flutter/flutter-intellij/issues/2250). However, if you run your project from IntelliJ, rather than launching it seperately and then trying to attach, debugging should work normally.